# Free space on my jailbroken iOS device is rapidly declining -- how do I figure out why?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Between yesterday and today, my iPhone 4 on Pangu 7.1.2 has gone from 2 gigs of data usage to 9 gigs.  I removed all of my videos and images.  Why the rapid jump?

My apps:
Messages, Calendar, Photos, Camera, Weather, Clock, Maps, Videos, Notes, Reminders, Game Center, iTunes Store, App Store, Settings, Line, SKype, Phone, Mail, Safari, Music, Extras, Voice Memos, FaceTime, Newstand, WeChat, Tether, Passbook, Gmail, Messenger, SpecialEffectsCamera, Swing Copters, Asphalt8, Angry Birds, Angry Birds Rio, Time Zones, Stocks, Facebook, Talkatone, Jango, LSATMax, LSAT #, LSAT Proctor, and Cydia.  Also: iCloud.

Comment: What is listed under Settings > General > Usage? I found that the Messages app was consuming 4GB on my iPhone 5 before I restored the device to factory settings.

Comment: Could be any of them. When you say data usage you mean just that, network data usage ? or the disk ?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually an issue with being unable to properly remove temporary data.

It's root cause could be one of two things:
1. The permissions for the .Trash service is corrupt

Or

1. There is issues in the directory of the storage component.

Either way the solution is to restore the device and setup as a new iPhone.
Erase all content and settings should work fine too if it wasn't jail broken.

Happy travels!